# Water pressure spikes inside home

Tags: water, pressure

It started with hammering in the master bath toilet when water would start to fill tank. Checked pressure coming into home and it was 120. Had PRV replaced to get pressure down. Now the pressure spikes several times a day up to between 80-100 and it’s set at 50!
If I turn the laundry tub faucet on for a couple seconds it goes right back down. But later in the day it will build back up.
Could it be the overflow tank pressure or a faulty tank? I had that replaced also but don’t think the plumber ever checked or set the psi. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have classic signs of water hammer. When shutting the valve of slowly it would be ok but rapidly it will bang. There are anti hammering devices you can install. Also since you have a pressure tank you need to turn off the incoming water and run your house down to zero. At this point you need to check the air pressure on the tank. Just a guess but it will be about 45 PSIG. If not adjust it and turn the system back on. On my system I have two 10' 1 1/2" copper pipes mounted vertical with a cap on the high end and the low end on the incoming cold water, it works good.